# How can I get a list of all packages built with yocto (for software bill of materials)?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I'm using yocto to build linux for am embedded device.  I need to produce a software bill of materials (SBOM), which will mostly consist of a list of the packages included in the build, their version numbers, and dependencies.  I've managed to find all this metadata in the tmp/pkgdata directory.  However, I've hit a problem in that pkgdata isn't just for the most recent build.  If I remove a package, for example, and then rebuild, that package will still exist in pkgdata.  So really what I need is a list of packages that were included in my most recent build (included packages that were cached and didn't need to be recompiled).

Does anyone know how I might go about acquiring such a list?  Once I know the package names, I should be able to pull everything else I need from the pkgdata directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `bitbake -g` to generate the build list. [This resource](https://docs.ota.here.com/ota-client/latest/useful-bitbake-commands.html#_list_all_packages_that_will_be_built_in_an_imagepackage) might help as well.

Comment: Thanks!  This is perfect.  I can use the output of this to key in to the tmp/pkgdata directory and that should get me everything I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use their built-in SBOM generation ability:
https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev/dev-manual/sbom.html